# multiple document.getElementById text not working for pictures in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, image, dictionary, iframe

I'd like to make a very simple online picture dictionary script where a child can type in a word (from a list of say ten words), in one text box, and a picture pops up in an iframe. Example, type in "dog" and a dog picture pops up in the iframe. Type in "cat" in the same text box, and a cat picture pops up in the same iframe. For the code that I have, I've included three words and three pictures, dog, cat and bird. But only the third word, "bird", works, the bird picture pops up. The first two words, dog, and cat are not working. I think it's because we can't have multiple document.getElementbyId, am I correct? If so, is there another workaround or alternative for this? A simple, shortest script if possible, that will be easy for me to add words to. I would like all the pictures to pop up in the same iframe box.

```js
function answer1() {
  if (document.getElementById("DICTIONARY").value == "dog")
    iframe.location.href = "dog.png"
  else
    iframe.location.href = "blank.png";
}

function answer2() {
  if (document.getElementById("DICTIONARY").value == "cat")
    iframe.location.href = "cat.png"
  else
    iframe.location.href = "blank.png";
}

function answer3() {
  if (document.getElementById("DICTIONARY").value == "bird")
    iframe.location.href = "bird.png"
  else
    iframe.location.href = "blank.png";
}
```

```html
<input id="DICTIONARY" type="text" size="8" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 20pt" />
<input type="button" value="GO" onclick="answer1();answer2();answer3();" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold" />
<br>

<br>
<iframe name="iframe" width="400" height="250"></iframe> &nbsp;
</td>
```

Comment: Your code calls all three functions on a "click" event on the button. The "bird" one works because it is the *last* function called. If you type "cat" in the text field, then the third function (the "bird" function) will load the "blank" image over the "cat" image. Also, you can call `getElementById()` as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need only one function. Have it load the "blank" image *first*, then get the value of the text field. You can then check the different good values, and if there's a match you can load that image over the blank image.

```
function answer() {
    iframe.location.href = "blank.png";
    let value = document.getElementById("DICTIONARY").value;
    switch (value) {
       case "dog": iframe.location.href = "dog.png"; break;
       case "cat": iframe.location.href = "cat.png"; break;
       case "bird": iframe.location.href = "bird.png"; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan I was trying to be clear for pedagogical purposes. I would of course write completely different code were I actually displaying animal photos on my own site.

Answer (score 0):

You only want one function here

Here is a recommended way to do what you want

I use a form, because then you can press enter when you type the word

I moved the CSS to a stylesheet and use eventListeners instead of onclick

Also no need to use an iFrame when you have a perfectly good img tag you can use

```js
const addresses = {
  'dog': 'dog.png',
  'bird': 'bird.png',
  'cat': 'cat.png'
};
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const inputField = document.getElementById('dictionary');
  const image = document.getElementById('image');
  document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submit
    const img = addresses[inputField.value]
    image.src = img ? img : 'blank.png'; // if found change 
  })
})
```

```css
#dictionary {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 20pt
}

#goButton {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="dictionary" type="text" size="8" />
  <input type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>
<img src="blank.png" id="image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
    <script>
    function answer1()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("DICTIONARY").value=="dog")
            iframe.location.href="dog.png";
        else if(document.getElementById("DICTIONARY").value=="cat")
            iframe.location.href="cat.png";
        else if (document.getElementById("DICTIONARY").value=="bird")
            iframe.location.href="bird.png"    
        else
            iframe.location.href="blank.png";    
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <input id="DICTIONARY" type="text" size="8" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 20pt"/>
    <input type="button" value="GO" onclick="answer1();" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <iframe name="iframe" width="400" height="250"></iframe>
    &nbsp;</td>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: DRY - Don't repeat yourself. Get the value ONCE and change the location ONCE

Answer (score -1):

Add a "default.png" if someone write something else in the DICTIONARY.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="button" value="GO" onclick="answer();" style="font-family:  Verdana; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold" />

// JavaScript
function answer() {
        let value = document.getElementById("DICTIONARY").value;
        switch (value) {
           case "dog": iframe.location.href = "dog.png"; break;
           case "cat": iframe.location.href = "cat.png"; break;
           case "bird": iframe.location.href = "bird.png"; break;
           default: iframe.location.href = "default.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't steal code and make tiny changes. The original already had a default